# Transformation of a cylinder with three.js

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, geometry

The HTML snippet below generates a rotating cylinder with **three.js**. The piece of code generating the animation is:

```js
const O = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const alpha = Math.PI / 180;
const Malpha = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(alpha), Math.cos(alpha), 0);
function animate() {
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, J);
  UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, Malpha);
  render();
}
```

The `UPDATE` function is:

```js
const radius = 0.07;
// geomUnitCylinder is a cylinder such that:
// - the center of the first base is (0, 0, 0)
// - the center of the second base is (0, 1, 0)
let geomUnitCylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(radius, radius, 1, 64, 1, true);
geomUnitCylinder.translate(0, 0.5, 0);

const J = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
// UPDATE(geomUnitCylinder, P, Q) transforms geomUnitCylinder to 
//   a cylinder with base centers P and Q.
function UPDATE(geomCylinder, P, Q) { 
  let vec = Q.clone().sub(P);
  const h = vec.length();
  vec.normalize();
  const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(J, vec);
  geomCylinder.scale(1, h, 1);
  geomCylinder.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
  geomCylinder.translate(P.x, P.y, P.z);
}
```

Now, I would like to create a similar animation but with another path for the endpoint of the cylinder (the "path" here is a circle). Something like that:

```js
let Path = [
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3),
  ......
];

let k = 0;
function animate() {
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  NEWUPDATE(geomCylinder, Path[k]);
  k++;
  render();
}
```

What would be the `NEWUPDATE` function? I don't want to destroy the current scene and recreate a new cylinder at each iteration, this is not efficient.

My real `Path` is a bit complicated, it is not an iteration of a simple transformation.

```js
const radius = 0.07;
// geomUnitCylinder is a cylinder such that:
// - the center of the first base is (0, 0, 0)
// - the center of the second base is (0, 1, 0)
let geomUnitCylinder = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(
  radius,
  radius,
  1,
  64,
  1,
  true
);
geomUnitCylinder.translate(0, 0.5, 0);

const J = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
// UPDATE(geomUnitCylinder, P, Q) transforms geomUnitCylinder to
//   a cylinder with base centers P and Q.
function UPDATE(geomCylinder, P, Q) {
  let vec = Q.clone().sub(P);
  const h = vec.length();
  vec.normalize();
  const quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(J, vec);
  geomCylinder.scale(1, h, 1);
  geomCylinder.applyQuaternion(quaternion);
  geomCylinder.translate(P.x, P.y, P.z);
}

// three js scene --------------------------------------------------------

const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, aspect, 1, 10000);
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x111111);
object = new THREE.Object3D();
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 5;
scene.add(camera);
function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
var geomCylinder = geomUnitCylinder.clone();
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomCylinder, material);
var object = new THREE.Object3D();
object.add(mesh);
scene.add(object);

window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
  return function (callback) {
    window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 1);
  };
})();

const O = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const alpha = Math.PI / 180;
const Malpha = new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(alpha), Math.cos(alpha), 0);
function animate() {
  requestAnimFrame(animate);
  UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, J);
  UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, Malpha);
  render();
}

animate();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.151.2/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

One idea that I considered but wouldn't work is to take a rotation `ROT` that sends `Path[k-1]` to `Path[k]` and define `M = ROT(O)` then use `UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, J); UPDATE(geomCylinder, O, M);`. *Maybe* it works *if it possible* (I don't know): it is *not* possible for my real path because the norm of the points forming the path is not constant, so there's no rotation sending a point of the path to the next point.

Comment: On a JS note, especially if you want others to read your code: better to stick to JS conventions and call it `update()` and `newUpdate()`, not `UPDATE()` and `NEWUPDATE()`. Three's own insistence to break with conventions is not something to copy =D (same for things like `Malpha`, `Path`, etc. Those should just be `mAlpha`, `path`, etc, Classes use UpperCamelCase, variables and functions use lowerCamelCase, true constants use UPPER_SNAKE_CASE). Also, why are you creating your own `requestAnimFrame` when `requestAnimationFrame` already exists?

Comment: Create a cylinder _geometry_ that is aligned with the _positive z-axis_ and has its base at the origin. Then, in your render loop, use `mesh.lookAt( desired_point_on_path )`.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks. Actually your colleague showed me the way on discourse.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the edit. I didn't know that `requestAnimationFrame` allows to control the speed.

Comment: It doesn't, but you also shouldn't: you can't control the time betweens calls in JS, you can only control "the minimum number of milliseconds" so timeout/interval does NOT run at your indicated speed, it runs _at most_ at that speed, and will _never_ run faster than once every 4~5 milliseconds after the first few timeouts (as per the JS timer spec). So what you do instead is you have have a variable that tracks "when your draw/update gets called" and then check how many ms passed since the last call. Then you use _that_ value to update all your time dependent values (e.g. angle over time).